# Is it possible to enable Portrait Mode (depth effect) on UIImagePickerController's camera?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app that should let the user take a selfie photo using the device's camera and it would be nice if the user could select Portrait Mode, just like in the Camera app.

Is it possible to enable Portrait Mode using UIImagePickerController?

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.cameraDevice = .front
```

This configuration allows only for a normal photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

The documentation says:

> When capturing a photo in the iOS Camera app, you can cause the portrait effects matte to be generated by entering Portrait mode and detecting a face. You can tell whether the camera found a face by checking for four yellow brackets in the viewfinder; photographing a detected face in Portrait mode doesn't guarantee the generation of a matte, but it is a prerequisite.
> Like the iOS Camera app, your app can also opt in for creating and embedding portrait effects matte into captured photos, eventually saving them as HEIC and JPEG images. Using AVFoundation’s AVCapturePhotoOutput, your app can find out whether a particular camera configuration supports the delivery of a portrait effect mattes to still images, and opt in to have them delivered on a per-photo request basis. AVCapturePhotoOutput delivers photo results using an in-memory wrapper object called AVCapturePhoto.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avportraiteffectsmatte/configuring_camera_capture_to_collect_a_portrait_effects_matte

`UIImagePickerController` is a very old framework that offered basic hardware <-> image integration. It does have some very nice hooks for basic camera features, but the last update was for Live Photo. For the newer camera features, it says:

> Perform fully-customized media capture and browsing
> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the AVFoundation framework as described in Still and Video Media Capture. Camera access using the AVFoundation framework is available starting in iOS 4.0.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller